# Scheduling R Script

Tags: r, windows, schedule, r-faq

I have written an R script that pulls some data from a database, performs several operations on it and post the output to a new database.

I would like this script to run every day at a specific time but I can not find any way to do this effectively.

Can anyone recommend a resource I could look at to solve this issue? I am running this script on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 119):

Actually under Windows you do not even have to create a batch file first to use the **Scheduler**.

- Open the scheduler: START -> All Programs -> Accesories ->  System Tools -> Scheduler
- Create a **new Task**
- under tab Action, create a **new action**
- choose **Start Program**
- browse to **Rscript.exe** which should be placed e.g. here: 

  **"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe"**
- input the name of your file in the **parameters** field
- input the path where the script is to be found in the **Start in** field
- go to the **Triggers** tab
- create **new trigger**
- choose that task should be done **each day**, month, ... repeated several times, or whatever you like

Comment: Yes, thank you!  This is what worked for me, not the above and not the various other answers floating around the web.  I would only add that make sure the file extension is `.R` and NOT `.r`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that - what would you expect to happen? Maybe this should go into an question of its own (maybe there is an answer already on SO).

Comment: Is there a way the dos window be minimized?

Answer (score 61):

Supposing your R script is `mytest.r`, located in `D:\mydocuments\`, you can create a batch file including the following command:

```
C:\R\R-2.10.1\bin\Rcmd.exe BATCH D:\mydocuments\mytest.r
```

Then add it, as a new task, to windows task scheduler, setting there the triggering conditions.

You could also omit the batch file. Set `C:\R\R-2.10.1\bin\Rcmd.exe` in the `program/script` textbox in task scheduler, and give as `Arguments` the rest of the initial command: `BATCH D:\mydocuments\mytest.r`

[Scheduling R Tasks via Windows Task Scheduler](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/scheduling-r-tasks-via-windows-task-scheduler/) (Posted on February 11, 2015)

[taskscheduleR: R package to schedule R scripts with the Windows task manager](http://bnosac.be/index.php/blog/50-taskscheduler-r-package-to-schedule-r-scripts-with-the-windows-task-manager-2) (Posted on March 17, 2016)

**EDIT**

I recently adopted the use of batch files again, because I wanted the cmd window to be minimized (I couldn't find another way).

Specifically, I fill the windows task scheduler `Actions` tab as follows:

`Program/script:`

cmd.exe

`Add arguments (optional):`

/c start /min D:\mydocuments\mytest.bat ^& exit

*Contents of mytest.bat*:

C:\R\R-3.5.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe D:\mydocuments\mytest.r params

Comment: Using `Rscript` is preferable to `R BATCH`. Systems that can differentiate between lower- and upper-case get `r` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't used it. As I saw, arguments can also be passed to the script and be accessed using commandArgs

Answer (score 12):

Now there is built in option in RStudio to do this, to run scheduler first install below packages

```
  install.packages('data.table')
  install.packages('knitr')
  install.packages('miniUI')
  install.packages('shiny')
  install.packages("taskscheduleR", repos = "http://www.datatailor.be/rcube", type = 
  "source")
```

After installing go to

```
**TOOLS -> ADDINS ->BROWSE ADDINS ->taskscheduleR -> Select it and execute it.**
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I try to run the Addin, I get the following errors:
Loading required namespace: shiny
Failed with error:  ‘number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)’
Loading required namespace: miniUI
Failed with error:  ‘number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)’
Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Comment: Just updated data.table to try and fix this error, and now I get the following: Error: object 'as.xts' not found whilst loading namespace 'data.table'

Comment: Does RStudio need to remain open for these to work?

Comment: I think if R studio is close it will automatically open it and run the script.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. I think the options using task scheduler in Windows couldn't find my libraries.

Comment: No actually it won't open R, it only opens a cmd window and executes the R script saved in the "Rscript repo" location (that you set above) in the background. An extra note for this option: the default running directory is in the system folder, just use `setwd` to get the directories right. Using `here` package won't work in this case.

Answer (score 8):

**Setting up the task scheduler**

Step 1) Open the task scheduler (Start > search Task Scheduler)

Step 2) Click "Action" > "Create Task"

Step 3) Select "Run only when the user is logged on", uncheck "Run with highest priveledges", name your task,
configure for "Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008"

[image]

Step 4) Under the "Triggers" tab, set when you would like the script to run

Step 5) Under the "Actions" tab, put the full location of the Rscript.exe file, i.e.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\Rscript.exe" (include the quotes)
```

Put the name of your script with with `-e` and `source()` in arguments wrapping it like this:

```
-e "source('C:/location_of_my_script/test.R')"
```

[image]

**Troubleshooting a Rscript scheduled in the Task Scheduler**

When you run a script using the Task Scheduler, it is difficult to troubleshoot any issues because you don't get any error messages.

This can be resolved by using the `sink()` function in R which will allow you to output all error messages to a file that you specify. Here is how you can do this:

```
# Set up error log ------------------------------------------------------------
error_log <- file("C:/location_of_my_script/error_log.Rout", open="wt")
sink(error_log, type="message")

try({

# insert your code here

})
```

The other thing that you will have to change to make your Rscript work is to specify the full file path of any file paths in your script.

This will not work in task scheduler:

```
source("./functions/import_function.R")
```

You will need to specify the full file path of any scripts you are sourcing within your Rscript:

```
source("C:/location_of_my_script/functions/import_function.R")
```

Additionally, I would remove any special characters from any file paths that you are referencing in your R script. For example:

```
df <- fread("C:/location_of_my_data/file#2342.csv")
```

may not run. Instead, try:

```
df <- fread("C:/location_of_my_data/file_2342.csv")
```

**Changing windows passwords**
Beware: Changing windows passwords will pause your task scheduler script(s). You will need to log back into the task scheduler and enter your password to get them started again.

Comment: Thanks for the note about source files! It's just what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

I set up my tasks via the `SCHTASKS` program. For running scripts on startup, you would write something along the lines of

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONSTART /TN MyProgram /TR "R CMD BATCH --vanilla d:\path\to\script.R"
```

See [this website](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/schtasks.php) for more details on `SCHTASKS`. More details at [Microsoft's website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

After following any combination of these steps and you receive the `"Argument Batch Ignored"` error after R.exe runs, try this, it worked for me.

In Windows Task Scheduler:

Replace `BATCH "C:\Users\desktop\yourscript.R"`in the arguments field

with

`CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\desktop\yourscript.R"`

Comment: This would make sense as a comment on Mark Byers' answer (or maybe an edit to that answer), I don't think it can stand alone.