# get online data every hour in R

Tags: r, scheduling

I would like to get the Observatory data every hour they update the forecast.

My one time data extract code is following.

```
library(RCurl)
web <- getURL("http://www.hko.gov.hk/contente.htm")
web <- unlist(strsplit(web, "\r\n"))
head(web)

temp <- unlist(strsplit(web[1245], "</span>"))
MINtemp <- vector()
MAXtemp <- vector()
for (i in 1:9){
    mintemp <- substr(temp[2*i-1], 
              nchar(temp[2*i-1])-1, 
              nchar(temp[2*i-1]))
    mintemp <- as.numeric(mintemp)
    MINtemp <- append(MINtemp, mintemp)

    maxtemp <- substr(temp[2*i], 
              nchar(temp[2*i])-1, 
              nchar(temp[2*i]))
    maxtemp <- as.numeric(maxtemp)
    MAXtemp <- append(MAXtemp, maxtemp)
}

status <- strsplit(
             substring(web[1242],12),
        "</a></td><td align")
status <- substring(unlist(status), 178)
weather <- vector()
for (i in 1:9){
    status[i] <- unlist(strsplit(status[i], "width"))[1]
    weather <- append(weather, 
                substr(status[i], 
                     1,
                     nchar(status[i])-3
                     )
                )
}

RH <- unlist(strsplit(web[1248], "</span>"))
MINRH <- vector()
MAXRH <- vector()
for (i in 1:9){
    minRH <- substr(RH[2*i-1], 
              nchar(RH[2*i-1])-1, 
              nchar(RH[2*i-1]))
    minRH <- as.numeric(minRH)
    MINRH <- append(MINRH, minRH)

    maxRH <- substr(RH[2*i], 
              nchar(RH[2*i])-1, 
              nchar(RH[2*i]))
    maxRH <- as.numeric(maxRH)
    MAXRH <- append(MAXRH, maxRH)
}

forecast <- paste("+", 1:9, "day(s)", sep=" ")
current <- as.character(rep(Sys.time(),9))
DATA <- data.frame(cbind(current,forecast,MINtemp, MAXtemp, MINRH, MAXRH, weather))
DATA
```

The data i get is

```
> DATA

                  current   forecast MINtemp MAXtemp MINRH MAXRH                                                                          weather
    1 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 1 day(s)      21      25    80    95 Cloudy with a few showers and thunderstorms. Showers will be more frequent later
    2 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 2 day(s)      22      25    75    90                        Cloudy with showers. A few squally thunderstorms at first
    3 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 3 day(s)      21      24    75    95                                                        Cloudy with a few showers
    4 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 4 day(s)      22      25    80    95                                                        Cloudy with a few showers
    5 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 5 day(s)      23      26    80    95                              Cloudy with showers and a few squally thunderstorms
    6 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 6 day(s)      23      26    80    95   Cloudy with showers. Showers will be heavy at times with squally thunderstorms
    7 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 7 day(s)      22      25    80    95                                    Cloudy with showers and squally thunderstorms
    8 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 8 day(s)      22      25    70    95                                                 Mainly cloudy with a few showers
    9 2014-05-04 08:37:55 + 9 day(s)      22      26    70    90                                                                    Mainly cloudy
```

I would like the R script run by itself every hour. Then use `rbind(DATA, data)` to accumulate the dataset. I search similar topic using CMD R BATCH. While can i do that within R like using `Sys.sleep()` and `while(substr(Sys.time(), 15,16)=="00")`?

I have searched similar task for scheduling [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/automating-r-script)

That i found Rscript.exe in the directory `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe`

and i saved my Rscipt at `D:\mydocument\test.r` While i still not clear that how to complete the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reasonable course of action is to **write a script** that does all you want to do (downloading data, cleansing, storing, ...) and than use something like:

- Task Scheduler under Windows [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21548386/1144966)
- Cronjob under Linux [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/using-cron.html)
- ICal, crontab,  CronniX, Maintidget, Macaroni and MacJanitor, Auto Scheduled Task, Launchd Editor, launchctl on Mac [link](https://superuser.com/questions/44849/user-friendly-way-to-schedule-jobs-in-mac-os-x)

... to **schedule it** - meaning to start it at regular intervals instead of having one R session run and waiting all the time via e.g. `Sys.sleep(60*60)`.

Answer (score 9):

You probably could use `Sys.sleep()` but it [smells like bad code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Instead, set up a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run your code updating every hour.  Then your script is simple, and more robust.

Comment: Hi, indeed i am new to programming. I don't even know how to complete the task with the bad code XD Sys.sleep() with while loop that substr(Sys.time(), 15,16)=="00" ?

Comment: What a big waste of system resources. Keeping an R instance cycling for the sole purpose of waking up every 60 minutes?