# Scheduling R code execution

Tags: r, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule an R code execution. I was referrig [Scheduling R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script) and I am creating the following batch file:

```
C:\R\R-2.10.1\bin\Rcmd.exe BATCH D:\mydocuments\mycode.R
```

However, when I run the .bat file, a black command window shows up for a second and nothing else is happening. I was also trying to use `Rscript.exe` instead of `Rcmd.exe`, but that did not help.

Have you got any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
r <- matrix(rnorm(100,1,1), ncol=10, nrow=10)
write.csv(r, file = "D:/aa/ttt.csv", row.names = F)
```

What I get after running the .bat file is the workspace and .Rout file, but this contains only a log of the code that was ran.

[image]

Comment: See http://www.statmethods.net/interface/batch.html

Comment: @amwill04 I have also tried that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? "black command window shows up for a second" should be exactly what you should be expecting in this case.

Comment: @AlexanderRadev So that, where does the output go?

Comment: @AlexanderRadev For example, my code should create some files, but it is not doing that, so that I concluded it is not ran properly.

Comment: Post the R code.  We can't know where your output would be if we can't see the script.

Comment: Can you append 'pause'  on the line after the call to R so that the window does not disappear and post a screenshot?

Comment: @AlexanderRadev Picture added to the original post.

Comment: The main problem is that the .csv file is not being generated; output is in the saved workspace though.

Comment: Can you try substituting 'write.csv(r, file = "D:/aa/ttt.csv", row.names = F)' with 'write.csv(r, file = file.path("D:", "aa" , "ttt.csv"), row.names = F)' or if the bat file is located in D:\aa - simply use ' 'write.csv(r, file = "ttt.csv", row.names = F)'?

Comment: @AlexanderRadev It works, thank you! Do you know what can be a reason for that or most important - when could this problem occur again? Only in the case of exporting files?

Comment: File path should always be created with the R function  file.path in order to avoid such bugs. Will promote my comment to an answer :)

Comment: I think your path should have been separated with double backslash characters not forward slashes.  e.g. `D:\\aa\\ttt.csv` .  I don't have R to test with but a little research showed that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting `write.csv(r, file = "D:/aa/ttt.csv", row.names = F)` with `write.csv(r, file = file.path("D:", "aa" , "ttt.csv"), row.names = F)`.

If the bat file is located in D:\aa - simply use `write.csv(r, file = "ttt.csv", row.names = F)`

Comment: I really appreciate your help!