# Scheduling task in R using Rselenium not working

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, rselenium

I try to automatically run an R script in Windows 8 using task scheduler as petermeissner explains in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script) thread. Below I pasted (part of) the script. The script does everything until `remDr$getPageSourece()`. I get a pop-up message saying 'R for Windows front-end has stopped working'. However, if I run the script in R (so not using scheduler) no error occurs. What can be possibly wrong?

```
pacman::p_load(RSelenium)
appurl <- "https://prod.beeline.com/ucb/Security/NewLogin.aspx?Url=%2fucb"
setwd("../downloaded")

RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()

Sys.sleep(5) 

remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(browserName="chrome") #For chrome make sure the file 'chromedriver is under 'downloaded'. Also this file can be found on TFS

remDr$open(silent=T)
remDr$navigate(appurl) 
Sys.sleep(1)
remDr$findElement(using = "css selector","#beelineForm_UserLoginForm_userNameText")$sendKeysToElement(list("username"))
Sys.sleep(1)
remDr$findElement(using = "css selector","#beelineForm_UserLoginForm_passwordText")$sendKeysToElement(list("passwd"))
remDr$findElement("css selector", "#loginButton")$clickElement() 

appurlNew <- "https://prod.beeline.com/ucb/Procurement/Request/ProcurementRequestListScreen.ascx"
Sys.sleep(1)

remDr$navigate(appurlNew)
Sys.sleep(3)

x <- getwd()
write(x, file="workingdir1.txt")

remDr$getPageSource()
```

EDIT: I tried re-running the script in R and now it also seems to block at `remDr$getPageSource()`. R says it 'searches for a function definition' until the session aborts.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the R script in the same version of R when you check vs. what the task scheduler loads?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have only one version of R installed on my PC (R-3.2.2), so I suppose so?

Comment: Worth a shot. Sometimes people rely on the Rscript added to path on install, but forgot to update it when they move to another version of R. I assume you also use the direct link to your Rscript.exe as explained by petermeissner  - "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" or whatever.

Comment: Yes I use that direct link indeed. I am afraid I do not completely understand you. Should I update my R version?

Comment: No, it was just a thought :)

Comment: Ok thank you. Please also see my edit in the question. Maybe this looks familiar.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package you are using so I'm just guessing things I have had issues with in the past when running scheduled tasks. Perhaps try loading `methods`. It might be a dependency for your application, and it is not part of the base packages in Rscript.