# How can i schedule an R code to run without having my PC on? [web-hosting]

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I am wondering if it's possible to have relatively simple R code pull and feed data into say... a text file attached to an email without having to keep my PC on.

I have a web-scraping code here that use:

```
library(XML)
library(stringr)
```

to scrape some web data which i would like to save daily..

Putting that on a loop that runs every 24 hours would be relatively easy, but i don't want to keep my PC on or not able to use the R environment while this is running.

what are my options?

Comment: You could spin up an AWS (Amazon Web Services) EC2 instance on the free tier and run it as a cron job. There are prebuilt AMIs that already have RStudio Server set up and ready to go.

Comment: nice one. put that in an answer with this link and i'll accept it: http://strimas.com/r/rstudio-cloud-1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you spin up an AWS EC2 instance and set the script to run as a cron job on a daily basis.

Here's some resources:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI

http://strimas.com/r/rstudio-cloud-1

Requires a little bash but if you aren't familiar it's definitely worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can [schedule batch R scripts to run via the Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script). +1 for AWS and cron though - super easy to get going once you establish the EC2 instance and get R running on it.