# Running R Scripts With Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: r, rscript, windows-task-scheduler

I am attempting to run a saved R script using Windows Task Scheduler. When I run it it fails. In an attempt to troubleshoot the problem I created a small test R script

```
test <- function(){
print("test")
}
test()
```

I then create a small bat file with

```
"C:\R\R-3.4.4\bin\R.exe" "C:\Test.R"
```

When I attempt to manually run that .bat file R in the cmd line opens but its initial message is

```
"C:\R\R-3.4.4\bin\R.exe" "C:\Test.R"
ARGUMENT "C:\Test.R" __ignored__
```

and the script does not run.

Comment: What are you starting the task in?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script

Comment: I just execute the bat file and it opens cmd line.

Comment: No need to create a bat file, follow the instructions in the first answer of the linked question.