# Scheduling a Rscript via Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to schedule a Rscript via Rstudio. I am able to schedule the task in Windows Task Scheduler but I am not able to run it at the same time.

When I do so, it schedules the task to open the Rscript in RStudio, but I would like to run it as well. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: I'm use this one https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheduling R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script)