# Automatically Execute R Script When (text) File is Updated

Tags: r, file, operating-system, scheduling, execute

I want to automatically **run/ execute my R script when a Text file is updated**. So far, I only can schedule an execution of my R script for a specific time (per hour, daily or month) see ([Scheduling R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script)).

**So, if my Text file is updated, I want that R gets executed directly.**

I have tried to adjust the "trigger" tab in windows scheduler. But I couldn't figured that out.

Help is really appreciated! **Thanks in advance!**

Comment: One way is a scheduled script that regularly keeps track of the updates and executes the other script if updated.

Comment: Thanks Nate! Do you have an example perhaps? Appreciated!

Comment: Try a websearch for "Win32 Directory Change Notifications API" or the ".NET FileSystemWatcher() API" maybe you can find some small program that watches the file/directory for you, or a blogpost that helps you out.