# Unable to send email when the script is run with task scheduler

Tags: r, email, automation

I coded an R script in order to create mail alert every day at a predetermined time. When I manually execute the code, it works great and I can receive the email in no time. However, when I run the script with task scheduler, it just failed to get the task done.

Below is my code, and my question is did I make a mistake when assigning the task or writing the code?

```
library(mailR)

message1="hello"
message2="hello"

 send.mail(from ="xxxxxx@gmail.com",
      to = c("xxxxxx@gmail.com"),
      subject = "Summary of stock performance",
      #body =paste(message1,"\r\n",message2),
      body = paste("<p> Overall </p>",message1,"<p>",message2,"<p>"),
      #body = paste(message1,"\r\n",message2,"\r\n"),
      #body="hello",
      html = TRUE,
      inline = TRUE,
      smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "xxxxxx", passwd = "xxxxxxx", ssl = TRUE),
      authenticate = TRUE,
      send = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should remove your email address.

Comment: does it fail with any errors? or just not send anything?

Comment: @tmsdajpa Sorry my bad. I will fix it

Comment: @RAB When I run it no matter in rstudio or in command prompt, it ends up with no error. But it sends me an email only when I manually run it in rstudio

Comment: Are you actually using the task scheduler like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21548386/10447055 ?

Comment: @Gainz In action part of task scheduler, I entered "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.0\bin\Rscript.exe" in program/script line , and typed "C:\r project 1\mail_R_testing.R" in argument box. The difference compared with your version is the direction of the dashes.

Comment: Did you try adding another function to your testing script to make sure the task scheduler is working correctly?  E.g., send your e-mail and save a txt file.

Comment: That is a great idea. If I can see a text file, that means the script is run successfully.