# Schedule multiple R scripts to run sequentially

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I have multiple scripts naming R001.r, R002.r, and so on. I need to schedule them so that they run in a sequential manner one after the other. What would be the best approach to do this.

Comment: Hi please have look this link hope this will help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @LenGreski.. windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to wrap your `r` scripts in a caller `sh` file and then invoke it through terminal. Here is what I would do.

1. Open up a terminal or any text editor available and fill it up with the following commands:

   Rscript R0001.r
   Rscript R0002.r
   Rscript R0003.r
   ...

Save this file into something like call_my_scripts. You can then execute it via standard unix shell commands as follows:

`./call_my_scripts`

This will run sequentially by definition. Make sure you give exec permissions to the file before you invoke it as follows:

`chmod u+x call_my_scripts`