# R: Scheduling Tasks in Base R

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I am working with the R programming language.

I am interested in learning how to schedule jobs in R - for instance, suppose I want to run the script below every Monday at 12:00 AM:

```
## my_script (create some random numbers, put them in a data frame,
## and save this data frame as a "csv" file containing the date/time 
## at which the file was created):

a = rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,10,10)

my_data = data.frame(a,b)

write.csv(my_data, paste0("my_data", format(Sys.time(), "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M"), ".csv"))

#END
```

Reading on the internet, I found out two ways of doing this:

**1) First Way:**

Using the recently developed "taskscheduleR" package in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html), you can specify which scripts and at what frequency you would like them to be scheduled:

```
#save the above script as an R file (I am not sure what "extdata" is)
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "my_script.R", package = "taskscheduleR")

## Run every week on Saturday and Sunday at 09:10
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_sunsat", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "WEEKLY", starttime = "09:10", days = c('SUN', 'SAT'))
```

**2) Second Way:**

Jobs can also be scheduled using the "Windows Task Scheduler" - this can be seen over here: [Scheduling R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script)

**My Question:** Is it possible to do this ENTIRELY in Base R? That is, can this be done without directly using "Windows Task Scheduler" ?

For instance, suppose I save the above script as an "R file":

[image]

**Using only commands in Base R, is it possible to specify how often you want to run this script and then send this script to the "task scheduler" - only using commands in Base R?**

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking if base R has the ability to interface directly with the OS's scheduling system? The only way I can think of is if you put your Windows machine in "never sleep" and have R test every minute or so to start an action.

Comment: What kind of scheduling are you trying to do, "every hour", "every 5 minutes", "daily", or something else?

Comment: (1) by "using only commands in base R" do you mean that you *don't* want to load/make use of the `taskscheduleR` package? (2) if not, isn't the first way you described exactly what you want (you are not directly using the WTS, rather you're calling it via R); (3) are you looking for an OS-independent solution?

Comment: @BenBolker yes, that was one of my next points ... OS-agnostic is not likely possible (in my experience, perhaps I'm missing something). I think the only "OS-independent" way this can work is to have R running 24/7 in a busy loop of sorts.

Comment: it would be reasonably straightforward to write something that used `cron` on Linux/MacOS and the WTS on Windows ... ?