# R: Meaning of "extdata"?

Tags: r

Can someone please explain what "extdata" means in R?

For instance, I was looking at the "cronR" library in R (used for automatically scheduling jobs), and came across the term "extdata":

```
f <- system.file(package = "cronR", "extdata", "helloworld.R")
cmd <- cron_rscript(f)
cmd
cron_add(command = cmd, frequency = 'minutely',
id = 'test1', description = 'My process 1', tags = c('lab', 'xyz'))
cron_add(command = cmd, frequency = 'daily', at='7AM', id = 'test2')
cron_njobs()
cron_ls()
cron_clear(ask=TRUE)
cron_ls()
```

Similarly, the "taskscheduleR" package (also used for automatically scheduling jobs) also makes reference to "extdata":

```
library(taskscheduleR)
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "helloworld.R", package = "taskscheduleR")

## run script once within 62 seconds
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "ONCE", starttime = format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M"))
```

**My Question:** Can someone please explain what is "extdata"? Is this just some "formality" that needs to be added to the "system.file()" command? Can someone please explain its relevance here?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/cronR.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html

Comment: See [this section of the R packages guide](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data-extdata). `inst/extdata` is where packages store "external data" _e.g._ data files used for examples in the package documentation.

Comment: @  
neilfws : thank you so much for your reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a convention, not a formally defined term. (However, it's a convention defined by the *package authors* and coded in the package structure; it's not something you can change unless you mess around with the package structure yourself.) "extdata" is presumably short for "external data".

*However*, this doesn't mean that you need to use "extdata" when you are structuring your own code; you only need it when finding the files that are included by the package.  `cron_rscript("~/my_cron_jobs/foo.R")` should work fine (provided you actually have something there, and provided that the `~` == home directory shortcut works across OS, which I think it does).

`system.file()` takes a `package` argument, but otherwise strings its arguments together into a file path; i.e. `system.file(package = "cronR", "extdata", "helloworld.R")` means

- look in the system folder that R has set up for the `cronR` package (in my case that is `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/cronR`, but the precise location will vary by OS and configuration)
- within that folder look in the `extdata` folder
- within that folder look for `helloworld.R`

So this command will refer *in my case* to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/cronR/extdata/helloworld.R`.

Since "/" works as a path separator (at least when used from within R) for all current operating systems, you would get the same results from `system.file(package="cronR", "extdata/helloworld.R")`

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: Thank you so much for your answer! I think this clarifies it - It looks like I will always have to add the "extdata" argument when scheduling R jobs. After a few minutes, I will be able to formally accept your answer!

Comment: If you have time, could you please take a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825523/r-scheduling-tasks-in-base-r thank you so much!